# Error in passing the foreign key in the form for editing

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have two tables, one named Client and the other named Projects linked together via a foreign key (this is client_id, which is present in Projects).

Each project has an edit button; when I click to edit a project I have a form with all fields secured to it.

To edit a project I have to pass the client id (client_id) associated with that project.

To do this, I did the following:

**ROUTE**

```js
Route::get('/project/edit/{project}', [ProjectController::class, 'edit'])->name('project.edit');
```

**CONTROLLER**

```js
public function edit(Project $project)
    {
        $client_id = Project::select('client_id')->where('id',$project->id)->get();
        //dd($client_id);
        return view('project.edit', compact('project','client_id'));
    }
```

**VIEW**

```js
<div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 namelabel">
                <form action="{{route('project.store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="client_id" value="{{$client_id}}" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="name" class="form-label">Project name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{$project->name}}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="logo" class="form-label">Insert image</label>
                        <input type="file" name="logo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="project_start_date" class="form-label">Data init</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="project_start_date" value="{{$project->project_start_date}}">
                    </div>
                    <label for="description" class="form-label">Description</label>
                        <textarea name="description" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control">{{$project->description}}</textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-5">Modifica progetto</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I get the following error:

*Incorrect integer value: '[{"client_id":14}]' for column 'client_id' at row 1*

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks to those who will help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement

```
Project::select('client_id')->where('id',$project->id)->get()
```

does not return the client_id. It returns an Eloquent Collection of Projects with only the client_id Attribute.

You can chain the **pluck** function to extract only value and then you can call **first** to get the value from the collection.

```
Project::select('client_id')
  ->where('id',$project->id)
  ->get()
  ->pluck('client_id')
  ->first()
```

---

After checking your code in the full detail you don't need to do the select part at all.
You have already the Project Model so you can access all of it's fields directly.

```
$project->client_id
```

In your view you are doing this already with the name of the project:

```
{{$project->name}}
```

You can do the same with the client_id as well:

```
{{$project->client_id}}
```

Comment: Is there an easier way that allows you to do this? i am a beginner in laravel

Comment: see the edited version of my answer. hope this help's you.

Comment: So I can just add in the view `value = "{{$project-> client_id}}" ` without doing the query

Comment: yes, the data is already there. no query needed.

Comment: perfect, thank you infinitely